# How do I read keyboard input on a Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I've tried using the KeyUp and KeyDown events to read keyboard input but as soon as I place other controls on the Winform, the keys are not read. How do I make sure that the keys are read?

Comment: Did you mean it works for blank form and not working if there is a control?

Comment: Yes, as written in the answers below, it works for controls like button, textbox, etc. but when I place an User Control it stops working.

Comment: It is not supposed to work, keyboard input goes to the control with the focus.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to read input from the keyboard and visualize it on a user control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `KeyPreview = true` on your form to catch keyboard events.

**EDITED** to let you understand:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) 
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Stupid sample that receives keyboard events and drop if A was pressed.
If focus is in a textbox, you'll see that text is written, but not A!!

**EDITED AGAIN:**  I took this code from a VB.NET example.
In your usercontrol,  use the text box's "Keypress" event  to raise a "usercontrol event".
This code would be in your custom usercontrol:

```
'Declare the event
Event KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer) 

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    RaiseEvent KeyPress(KeyAscii)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bildsoe: I tried and it works. You should catch `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events on form: you'll get them, be sure. If not post your code please, because there should be something wrong...

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try over, I must have done something wrong. I have a user control on my form, does this change anything?

Comment: @Bildsoe: no, it doesn't change anything. With `KeyPreview = true` keyboard events are sent to form before controls...

Comment: I tried removing the user control and then it works. Also if I have textboxes, buttons etc. But not with user controls. Why is this?

Comment: I've looked at the example but I'm sure how to use it. I wire up an event on the textbox which raises an event on the containing form?

Comment: @Bildsoe: only in custom controls... they say... I've never tried it

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm not getting it to work, but your answer telling me to use KeyPreview=True on the form was still the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx

set `KeyPreview = true` and your `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` will recognize all keyboard input.

Answer (score 3):

As  marco says set KeyPreview to true on your form to catch the key events in the entire form rather than just a control.

Use the KeyPress event ... KeyUp/Down are more for the framework than your code. KeyDown is good if you want to disable a key ... numeric only fields etc. In general KeyPress is the one you're after.

If you want to prevent the keystrokes from propogating to other controls set KeyPressEventArgs.Handled = true.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=VS.90).aspx

Have you wired up the event handler?

```
MyForm.KeyDown += MyHandler;
```

You can also do this in the properties pane ... click the event icon ...

Comment: I need both up and down. I want to visualize the keys being pressed, so something needs to happen both on keyUp and keyDown.

Comment: ah I see ... KeyUp/Down should work just the same then. Have you wired up the event handlers? Either in the properties pane in the events section or in code? 

MyForm.KeyDown += MyEventHandler;

Comment: Yes I had wired up the event handler. It works, but not if I place an user control on the form then it stops working.

Comment: @iDevForFun: I tried setting `e.Handled = true` but keys are propagated. I had to set `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` (look at my post). Is it correct in your opinion?

Comment: You can only handle key down events for the control that has focus if KeyPreview is not set to true. I can only guess your user control is taking focus and preventing the key event from being propagated. 

Have you set KeyPreview to true?

Comment: @Marco I remember something about having to do that myself ... been a long time since I worked on winforms tho so a little rusty. :)

Comment: Yes, I have set KeyPreview true on the form, and the User Controls does not have this property.

Comment: Last attempt at a suggestion before I give up :) ... you have wired up the event handlers ... but on the form or the control? If you want to handle the events on the form regardless of which control has focus .. KeyPreview = true and wire up the event handler on the form .. not the control. I assume this is what you have done anyway but worth checking ... Good luck :)

Comment: @iDevForFun - yes this is what I have done. Thanks. I'm gonna try the RaiseEvent that Marco suggested to see if this can help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for your Form itself to read the keyboard input, you already have your answer from other correspondents. I am adding this contribution for the possibility that you might want to add key handling to other controls or user controls on your form. My article [Exploring Secrets of .NET Keystroke Handling](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/39607) published on DevX.com (alas, it does require a registration but it is free) gives you a comprehensive discussion on how and why all the various keyhandling hooks and events come into play. Furthermore, the article includes a "Keystroke Sandbox" utility for free download that actually lets you see which controls are receiving which key handling events.

Here is one illustration from the article to whet your appetite:

[image]